# Python 3.4 DeprecationWarning convert_charrefs

Tags: python-3.x, unit-testing

Using UnitTest in the shell:

```
python3.4 -m unittest my_test.py -v
```

I get the DeprecationWarning

```
DeprecationWarning: The value of convert_charrefs will become True in 3.5. You are encouraged to set the value explicitly.  super().__init__() ERROR
```

So it seems

```
super().__init__()
```

triggers this DeprecationWarning. But I can not find anything about convert_charrefs warning. Also the used statement is used in the Python documentation, and multiple examples in SO.

What causes this warning, and how can I solve this? Thanks.

Comment: `convert_charrefs` correspond to `HTMLParser`. If you inherit from this class you must explicitly specify convert_charrefs: `class Foo(HTMLParser): def __init__(self): super().__init__(convert_charrefs=True)`

Comment: Thats it. Solved. Thanks very much @Aiven

Comment: I want to accept your answer, but could not find where to do so.

Comment: You can't accept comment, but I can move it to the answers section (:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`convert_charrefs` correspond to `HTMLParser`. If you inherit from this class you must explicitly specify convert_charrefs:

```
class Foo(HTMLParser): 
  def __init__(self): 
    super().__init__(convert_charrefs=True)
```

Comment: Thanks, that did the job. Solved!