# webp2y XML helper sanitize line breaks under python3

Tags: python-3.x, web2py, html-sanitizing, xmlhelper

In my web2py app I’m processing a list of items, where the user can click on a link for each item to select this. An item has an UUID, a title and a description. For a better orientation the item description is also displayed as link title. To prevent injections by and to escape tags in the description I’m using the XML sanitizer as follows:

```
A(this_item.title, \
  callback = URL('item', 'select', \
                 vars=dict(uuid=this_item.uuid), user_signature=True), \
  _title=XML(str_replace(this_item.description, {'\r\n':'&#13;', '<':'&#60;', '>':'&#62;'}), sanitize=True))
```

Using Python 2 everything was fine. Since I have switched to Python 3 I have the following problem. When the description contains line breaks the sanitizer is not working anymore. For example the following string produces by my str_replace routine is fine to be sanitized by the XML helper under Python 2 but not under Python 3:

```
Header&#13;&#13;Line1&#13;Line2&#13;Line3
```

Sanitizing line breaks escaped by `&#13;` is the problem with Python 3 (but not with Python 2). Everything else is no problem for the XML helper to sanitize (e.g. less than or greater than, I need these, since if there is no description it is generated as `<no description>`).

How can be line breaks sanitized by the XML helper running web2py under Python3?

Thanks for any support!

Best regards
Clemens

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is down to a change in python's HTMLParser class between 3.4 and 3.5, where convert_charrefs started defaulting to True:
[Python 3.4 DeprecationWarning convert_charrefs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48203228/python-3-4-deprecationwarning-convert-charrefs)

I think the following fix in the your web2py yatl source should correct it:
https://github.com/web2py/yatl/compare/master...timnyborg:patch-1

Comment: Tim, thanks a lot! That's the solution!

Today I already established a simple workaround: First XML+sanitizer, then replacing line breaks in XML helper attribute text:

`item_title = XML(str_replace(this_activity.description,
                 {'<':'&#60;', '>':'&#62;'}), sanitize=True)
item_title.text = str_replace(item_title.text, {'\r\n':'&#13;'})

A(this_item.title, \
   callback = URL('item', 'select', \
                            vars=dict(uuid=this_item.uuid), user_signature=True), \
                           _title=item_title)))))`

But the fix is better!